# Use variable in global environment inside with or subset in r

Tags: r

I like using `with()` and `subset()` interactively, and sometimes I want to reference variables in the global environment. What is the best way to do that?

```r
d <- data.frame(x = TRUE)
x <- FALSE
with(d, x == x)
```

I want the last call to return `FALSE` by referencing the `x` variable in the global environment instead of comparing `x` inside the data.frame to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` has an argument to change the environment being referenced:

```r
d <- data.frame(x = TRUE)
x <- FALSE
with(d, x == get("x", envir = parent.frame(2)))
```

`parent.frame(2)` refers to the global environment.